# Having trouble modifying a Built-in WixUI dialog set

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I am trying to remove the license agreement from the built-in WixUI_InstallDir dialog set. I found some helpful instruction [here](http://www.howdoicode.net/2011/09/wix-how-to-hide-license-agreement.html)
I've added this to the Product.wxs

```
<UI Id="InstallDir">
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg">NOT Installed</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
</UI>
```

The next button on the welcome dialog happily goes to the install directory dialog, but the back button of InstallDirDlg goes to the license agreement.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question in the WiX-user mailing list. The consensus was that trying to change some of the publish commands in a built-in dialog set is not a "recipe for success". Instead I got the source wxs for the WixUI_InstallDir, made a copy of it (WixUI_NOEULAInstallDir), modified it and included in my project. I was trying to avoid having a custom dialog file in all my solutions, but I was able to export a project template that has the custom dialog included, so it's not so bad.